# How to get line number of selected node in xml using powershell

Tags: xml, powershell, line-numbers

I would want to get the line number of node which is changed/manipulated in XML using powershell.

$($node.LineNumber) doesn't seem to be working.

For example:

$node.ParentNode.InsertBefore($nodeToInsert, $node) //which inserts a node

I want to get the line number of this node.

Comment: Afaik, there is no way to do this. Line in `XML` files are just there for human readability they have no meaning for the the xml parser (for the xml parser you might as well remove all the linefeeds). Saying that, I discourage you to do anything with the line index (unless it is just for human intervention). If you do not agree, please add some more background to the question of *why* you want to do this. See also [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Lines and line numbers exist in the lexical XML that you supply as input to the XML parser. They don't exist (usually) in the tree of in-memory nodes that is output by the XML parser, and which your program is manipulating. Even if the nodes in the tree retain diagnostic information about the line numbers where they originally came from, it's certainly not a meaningful concept for nodes that are subsequently added to the tree.

You need to find a different way to solve whatever you are trying to accomplish.