# PowerShell XmlReader to XmlWriter, inline comments shifting to new line

Tags: xml, powershell

Given an XML file of

```
<root>
  <!-- Block comment -->
  <node />
  <!-- Block comment -->
  <node /> <!-- Inline comment -->
</root>
```

and this code

```
function Write-XmlToConsole ($xml) {
    $stringWriter = [System.Io.StringWriter]::new()
    $xmlWriter = [System.Xml.XmlTextWriter]::new($stringWriter)
    $xmlWriter.Formatting = "indented"
    $xmlWriter.Indentation = 4
    $xml.WriteTo($xmlWriter)
    $xmlWriter.Flush()
    $stringWriter.Flush()
    Write-Host $stringWriter.ToString()
    Write-Host
    Write-Host
}


$fileStream = [System.Io.fileStream]::New("$psScriptRoot\File.xml", [System.Io.FileMode]::Open, [System.Io.FileAccess]::Read, [System.Io.FileShare]::ReadWrite)

$xmlReaderSettings = [Xml.XmlReaderSettings]::new()
$xmlReaderSettings.CloseInput = $true
#$xmlReaderSettings.IgnoreComments = $true
$xmlReaderSettings.IgnoreProcessingInstructions = $true
$xmlReaderSettings.IgnoreWhitespace = $true

$xmlreader = [System.Xml.Xmlreader]::Create($fileStream, $xmlReaderSettings)

$importFile = [System.Xml.XmlDocument]::new()
$importFile.Load($xmlreader)
$importFile.Save("$psScriptRoot\New.xml")

Write-XmlToConsole $importFile
```

I would expect both the new file and the console output to match the original. However, the inline comment is being pushed to a new line in both cases. Am I missing a setting, either in the XmlReader or XmlWriter? Or is this just not possible?

Also, the reason I am concerned is I ultimately want to be able to validate XML in a way that doesn't lend itself to XSD, namely that some of the loaded XML will be used for the current workflow and some won't, so I want to validate and fail if the failed validation would affect the workflow, but if it wouldn't affect the workflow I want to continue while logging the validation failure so the user can address it before it would affect a workflow. And in that log I want provide the line number, which requires that comments be handled correctly so line number match. But a secondary issue is, how does one extract the line number of, for example, the last `<node />`?

EDIT: Further complicating things, if I make one of the two block comments a two line comment, such as

```
<!-- Block comment 
  Line 2 -->
```

I get an "Invalid character" error at the second `<node />` line that immediately follows the comment, but the XML validates just fine when copy/pasted into an only XML validator.

EDIT2: Not sure it matters, but the original XML file was created with NotePad ++.

EDIT3: If I don't have a true block comment, the output looks like

```
<root>
  <!-- Block comment -->
  <node />
  <!-- Block comment -->
  <node />
  <!-- Inline comment -->
</root>
```

If I change the second block comment to be a real block, like this

```
<root>
  <!-- Block comment -->
  <node />
  <!-- Block comment 
  Second Line -->
  <node />
  <!-- Inline comment -->
</root>
```

I get this error

```
Exception calling "Load" with "1" argument(s): "'.', hexadecimal value 0x00, is an invalid character. Line 7, position 8."
At \\Mac\iCloud Drive\Px Tools 4.#\# Dev 4.0\##Spikes\XML Comments handling\XMLcomments.ps1:27 char:1
```

Comment: XML comments are still XML nodes, and they'll be subjected to the same formatting settings as everything else your writer writes.

Comment: @ mathias-r-jessen I guess what I don't understand is why only comment are being treated this way. I can get all nodes on their own lines, or all nodes on a single line, but keeping inline comment nodes where they belong I can't do. It seems like NotePad++ and the validators know how to handle this, but perhaps it's a limitation of .NET that it can't? I guess worst case I can rewrite to a new line, so the line number I reference works. But that still begs the question, can a multiline comment be supported, and how do I get the actual line numbers from a given node?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know what you mean by "where they belong" and I can't reproduce the issue you describe with multi-line comments. Can you show us the exact output that you're actually getting? (please include both the output for your original question + modified input sample and full error for when you use multi-line comments.)

Comment: @mathias-r-jessen Updates the original post with more detail. Thanks!

Comment: "hexadecimal value 0x00" sounds like Notepad++ (or something else) inserted a null byte in or after your block comment

Comment: Ah, so possibly a bug in NotePad++. I guess the main question then is, CAN I even get at line numbers? If I can't then I will simply use the IgnoreComments option on XmlReader and end up with slightly lighter weight data. I'll juts need to find a way, other than line number, to direct the user to the correct node when something fails my "validation".

Comment: As for it being NotePad++, I tried find/replace on `\x00`, which is supposed to replace the null, and I am still seeing the error. So I start to wonder if it's not a .NET bug in the reader?

Comment: Arg! The multiple line issue was actually something janky in memory with the ISE. I closed, reopened and reran my script, and the block comment is now working fine. Still getting the inline comment on it's own line, but again that's not the end of the world if I can save the file in that state, and then provide a line number for an arbitrary node.

Comment: Aaaand, this might all be for naught, as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60665651/how-to-get-line-number-of-selected-node-in-xml-using-powershell suggests that line numbers are meaningless once the XML is converted from a file to an object. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However, the inline comment is being pushed to a new line in both cases

That's because XML comment nodes are **still XML nodes** - so if the formatting settings prescribe indenting sibling nodes on new lines, that'll apply to comment nodes as well :)

Comment: Aha, so what is the setting to NOT indent sibling nodes?

Comment: @Gordon I don't think the built-in xml writers have such a setting, that's just an effect of using indentation. You'd need to implement your own writer if you want special formatting for specific node types

Comment: @mathias-r-jessen I was afraid it would end up being a limitation of XmlReader. I need to do some testing with Linq, since I think that may be more fruitful, and I want to test performance too. I have another use case that involves REALLY massive XML files that I need to parse. Off down another rabbit hole.

Comment: @Gordon LINQ-to-XML might prove useful for parsing/reading large source documents, but I suspect you'll still have to implement a custom writer (which, for high-volume processing, I suggest you do in C#) FWIW